# iOS Linking Issues for iOS6 and Armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, ios6, armv7

I've recently opened my previously working apps (before i upgraded to the new Xcode for iOS6) and i'm getting some errors. I've redownloaded the frameworks that were kicking back the errors but those same frameworks now seem to be giving me more trouble. Below is the error...

```
Ld /Users/JohnSlater/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iFestApp-avmgjnvetjnjecdjprczkbgdkfas/Build/Intermediates/iFestApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/iFestApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/iFestApp normal armv7
    cd "/Users/JohnSlater/Desktop/iOS Apps/iFestival for V 2012"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -L/Users/JohnSlater/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iFestApp-avmgjnvetjnjecdjprczkbgdkfas/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "-L/Users/JohnSlater/Desktop/iOS Apps/iFestival for V 2012/iFestApp/Resources/Frameworks/Airship" -F/Users/JohnSlater/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iFestApp-avmgjnvetjnjecdjprczkbgdkfas/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/JohnSlater/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iFestApp-avmgjnvetjnjecdjprczkbgdkfas/Build/Intermediates/iFestApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/iFestApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/iFestApp.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework AudioToolbox -framework MessageUI -framework StoreKit -framework CoreTelephony -lsqlite3 -framework AVFoundation -lz -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lUAirship-1.3.3 -lUAirshipPush-1.3.3 -o /Users/JohnSlater/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iFestApp-avmgjnvetjnjecdjprczkbgdkfas/Build/Intermediates/iFestApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/iFestApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/iFestApp

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TestFlight", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlurryAnalytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone give me some guidance as i've been unable to find a straight answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the static library is compiled either for the simulator (i386) or older devices (ARMv6).

Comment: It sounds like your project architecture is armv7, but those libraries are for armv7s, the latest architecture (for iPhone 5). Not totally sure. Running into similar issues today as well. Look in Build Settings, under Architectures.

Comment: It's set to "standard (armv7, armv7s) - $" if thats any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support iPhone 5 configurations you have to reconfigure the whole project and make it run with armv7s architecture.

If you just want to get rid of the errors you should remove all the armv7s references, including all libs.

This may help a little: [Moving to iOS6 I get this linker error with almost all external packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398201/moving-to-ios6-i-get-this-linker-error-with-almost-all-external-packages/12410978#12410978)